# TFS 2015 RC Build vNext - Hangs on Code Coverage

Tags: msbuild, code-coverage, mstest, tfs-2015

I have TFS 2015 RC and VS 2015 RC ( Enterprise ) installed on the server.  I setup a simple test project with one msTest.  Setup a build that builds the app then runs the UnitTests in the next step.  I also set the build to Release and MsBuild x64.

If I check the "Code Coverage Enabled" checkbox in the test step, the build hangs after it runs the test.  Below is the trace, after the one test succeeds there is no more logging, i went to the _diag directory and the same shows in the logs.  I can't figure out how to make it more verbose.  I expected to see more logging from the vtest.ps1 powershell script.

```
    ******************************************************************************
Starting task: VSTest
******************************************************************************
Executing the powershell script: C:\TFS_Data\Build\tasks\VSTest\1.0.8\VSTest.ps1
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 14.0.22823.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Starting test execution, please wait...
Passed   HelloMs
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found out what is going on, vNext apparently can not coverage when you run xUnit tests.  It works with the Ms test framework though.